# Cryptanalysis of S-DES - Equations

Tags: cryptanalysis, s-des

I am trying to derive equations for `s` and `t` in the cryptanalysis of a Simple DES algorithm, but I haven't been able to deduce it. I have attached an image of the portion that I'm referring to, and I would appreciate it if someone could explain as to how the equations `q` and `r` are derived and what would be the derivation for `s` and `t`.

[image: Simple DES]

Comment: I'm not able to verify the equations in both the ways, so I'm not sure how the equations were derived.

Answer (score 3):

The question is actually about *Simplified* DES (rather than *Simple* DES as stated), which is an extremely simplified mock-up of [*Single* DES](http://csrc.nist.gov/publications/fips/fips46-3/fips46-3.pdf).

From reading the definition of S-DES in the [reference](http://mercury.webster.edu/aleshunas/COSC%205130/G-SDES.pdf) used in the question, we get that:

> The S-boxes operate as follows. The first and fourth input bits are treated as a 2-bit number that specify a row of the S-box, and the second and third input bits specify a column of the Sbox. The entry in that row and column, in base 2, is the 2-bit output.

[image]

Now let $a b c d$ be the input bits, $q r$ the output bits, use [big-endian](http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Big-endian) convention, and reformat that table as:

```
abcd qr     abcd qr    abcd qr    abcd qr
0000 01     0010 00    0100 11    0110 10
0001 11     0011 10    0101 01    0111 00
1000 00     1010 10    1100 01    1110 11
1001 11     1011 01    1101 11    1111 10
```

In order to *verify* the equations $q=abcd\oplus ab\oplus ac\oplus b\oplus d$ and $r=abcd\oplus abd\oplus ab\oplus ac\oplus ad\oplus a\oplus c\oplus 1$, just compute what $q$ and $r$ they give for each of the $2^4$ combinations of input, and compare that to the reformatted table; this is left as an exercise to the reader.

There is no systematic practical method to *derive* the most compact equation for a sizable bit table, and in the case of DES S-boxes this has been the subject of intense research. One systematic method leading to the most compact representation of an arbitrary boolean function as OR-of-AND-terms is known as [Karnaugh map](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karnaugh_map), but here the equations are wanted as XOR-of-AND-terms, and I know no analogous method. With 4 entries, finding the shortest equation (by some metric) that match would be tractable by brute force with a computer.

Still, here is how one of the equation could have been derived by hand. First we rewrite the table with the arguments in [Gray order](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gray_code)

```
a | 0000000011111111
b | 0000111111110000
c | 0011110000111100
d | 0110011001100110
--|-----------------
q | 0110100101111010
r | 1100110001011110
```

By comparing the line for $d$ with the line for $q$, it is striking that a bit flip of $d$ cause a flip in $q$, except when $a=b=c=1$; in other words, $q'=q\oplus d\oplus abcd$ is independent of $d$. We have reduced the problem to finding an equation for $q'$, with table

```
a | 00001111
b | 00111100
c | 01100110
--|---------
q'| 00110110
```

and some trial and error is enough to find $q'=ab\oplus ac\oplus b$, from which $q=abcd\oplus ab\oplus ac\oplus b\oplus d$ follows.

Answer (score 2):

A [Karnaugh map](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karnaugh_map) is definitely the way to go to understand the concept and derive the equations in a few binary variables.

If you want to do this for a larger numbers of variables, look into Quine-McCluskey. There's a sizable introductory literature in logic design that is relevant to this.

In general, since algebraic cryptanalysis involves doing a lot of algebraic normal form to conjunctive normal form (and vice-versa), it might be worth writing some kind of converter, or using one that is already available (e.g. Mathematica, SAGE).

Comment: Notice that the equations derived using a Karnaugh map are usually of the form OR-of-AND-terms, which is not the form thought in the question, where $+$ stands for addition modulo 2, that is XOR.

Comment: @fgrieu: You hit the nail on the head. My professor just pointed it out to me.